# file permission with sticky-bits not working

Tags: c

I am trying to get the file permission including the sticky-bits and GUID on a file attributes. It seems not to be working for all files.

```
char *permstr = malloc(sizeof(char) * LEN);

    snprintf(permstr, LEN, "%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", ftpe, (sb->st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? 'r' : '-', 
    (sb->st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? 'w' : '-', (sb->st_mode & S_ISUID) ? (sb->st_mode & S_IXUSR ? 's' : 'S') :
                                                  (sb->st_mode & S_IXUSR ? 'x' : '-'),

     (sb->st_mode && S_IRGRP) ? 'r' : '-', (sb->st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? 'w' : '-',
     (sb->st_mode & S_ISGID) ? (sb->st_mode & S_IXGRP ? 's' : 'S') : (sb->st_mode & S_IXGRP ? 'x' : '-'),

     (sb->st_mode & S_IROTH) ? 'r' : '-', (sb->st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? 'w' : '-',
     (sb->st_mode & S_ISVTX) ? (sb->st_mode & S_IXOTH ? 't' : 'T') : (sb->st_mode & S_IXOTH ? 'x' : '-'));
```

i tried it with some normal files but it works but there is one particular file it gives wrong output

but when i test it with the normale GNU Find command, it works well.
[image: testcase-screenshot]

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why are you using two different symbolic constants for the length of the string? Does `LEN` and `STR_SIZE` differ? And why do you need to explicitly add the string terminator, the `snprintf` should do that for you (if there's space). And if using a symbolic constant, why allocate dynamically to begin with, why not create a plain array?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank, i didn't know that. yea `sizeof(LEN),` `snprintf` was giving me errors, when i use `sizeo`f there so i decided to use a macro for it. is basiclly `sizeof(LEN)`

Comment: If your code works for some files but not others, then it would seem appropriate to say something about what distinguishes these kinds of files.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i have no idea what is going on there. It seems normally a normal file. I just run a bash script through all the times on the server and it fails. but from the results of the `GNU Find` is a normal file

Comment: You might also consider running the program in a debugger, or dumping the uninterpreted stat data, so as to compare what `stat` actually says about the file to how you're interpreting that.

Comment: Do you mean that `STR_SIZE` is `sizeof(LEN)`? That makes no sense. If `LEN` is a macro defined to be an integer, then `sizeof(LEN)` will be equal to `sizeof(int)` which is usually 4. That means you write only *three* characters to the string, plus the string terminator.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what do you suggest i do, because when i use the `sizeof(LEN)` in the snprintf it gives me an error

Comment: Also, by "sticky bits" do you just mean the bits of the mode bitmask generally?  A.k.a. permission bits?  The term "sticky bit" generally means something much more specific that does not appear to manifest in your example.

Comment: Don't pass `sizeof(LEN)` as the length of the string, that is the length of whatever *type* `LEN` expands to. Instead just pass `LEN`, plain and simple.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be because you are using `&&` instead of `&` in this: `sb->st_mode && S_IRGRP`

Comment: There's also an open parenthesis missing at the start of the line that starts `sb->st_mode & S_ISGID)`.

Answer (score 1):

As a formatting suggestion, please consider:

```
snprintf(permstr, STR_SIZE, "%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", ftpe,
            (sb->st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? 'r' : '-',
            (sb->st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? 'w' : '-',
            (sb->st_mode & S_ISUID) ? (sb->st_mode & S_IXUSR ? 's' : 'S') :
                                      (sb->st_mode & S_IXUSR ? 'x' : '-'),

            (sb->st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? 'r' : '-',    // Fix 1 (&& --> &)
            (sb->st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? 'w' : '-',    // Fix 2 (prefix '(')
            (sb->st_mode & S_ISGID) ? (sb->st_mode & S_IXGRP ? 's' : 'S') :
                                      (sb->st_mode & S_IXGRP ? 'x' : '-'),

            (sb->st_mode & S_IROTH) ? 'r' : '-',
            (sb->st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? 'w' : '-',
            (sb->st_mode & S_ISVTX) ? (sb->st_mode & S_IXOTH ? 't' : 'T') :
                                      (sb->st_mode & S_IXOTH ? 'x' : '-')
        );
```

That at least makes it easier to see what's going on.  I'm sure there'll be some disagreement about the finest points of the indentation (should the 'per-bit' lines be indented 3 spaces left — that would be OK too; should the file type `ftpe` be on a line on its own, too), but the overall idea of making the symmetry between the structures clearer helps with the readability.

I'll observe that both the fixes were dead easy to spot in this format.

<sup>*Please do not accept this as 'the' answer; just consider it as advice on layout that cannot be demonstrated in a comment.  It's a formatted comment as much as it is an answer.*</sup>

Comment: Thanks man, that is clean. I got to learn how to keep good formats when am hot coding